# How to add a new column to a Pandas Dataframe based on data both in each row, and on the existence of other rows that meet a specific criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, where-clause

I'm looking to take my existing DF with a number of columns and perform the following operation:

```
For each originalRow in the DF
check if another row exists where: 
row.col1 = originalRow.col1,
 and 
row.col2 != originalRow.col2
```

Is there a way to do this gracefully in Python / Pandas?

I've looked into using the .where operator, but the issue I run into is that my conditions are checking one rows column values against another rows values. (Something like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43481338/3757782, but for two different rows)

Something like:

```
df["New Col"] = np.where(((df["col1"] == df["col1*"]) && (df["col2"] != df["col2*"])), 1, 0)
```

Except that col1* has to be another row from col1, etc. Let me know if this question doesn't make sense. I'm hoping that this is something that isn't that hard, and I'm just missing what the standard way to do this is.

Thanks!

Example Data:

```
df = 
Col1, Col2
a, 1
a, 2
b, 1
b, 1
c, 1
c, 2
c, 3
d, 1
```

Expected Output:

```
df =
Col1, Col2, newCol
a, 1, 1
a, 2, 1
b, 1, 0
b, 1, 0
c, 1, 1
c, 2, 1
c, 3, 1
d, 1, 0
```

the two A rows get 1 (true) because another row exists for each of those where col1 = col1* and col2 != col2*

the two B rows get 0 (false) because they don't meet the condition

the three C rows get 1 (true) for the same reason as the A rows

and D gets 0 (false) as no other D row exists

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Comment: Will do, 1 sec.

Comment: If you're only stuck about the row versus column selector, you could use a df.T (it will transpose your dataframe)

Comment: Thank's for the suggestion @tgrandje, unfortunately since I'm trying to look at two rows and two columns, I don't think that transposing in this case is helpful, but than's for taking a look!

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
df['COUNT'] = 1

count = df.groupby(cols)['COUNT'].sum()
ix = df[df['COUNT']>1].index
count.loc[ix, 'COUNT'] = 0

df = df.merge(count, on=cols, how='left')
```

---

EDIT :

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
df['COUNT'] = 1

count = df.groupby(cols)['COUNT'].sum()
count = count.reset_index(drop=False)
ix = df[df['COUNT']>1].index
count.loc[ix, 'COUNT'] = 0

df = df.merge(count, on=cols, how='left')

count_col1 = df[['col1', 'COUNT']].copy()
count_col1 = df[['col1', 'COUNT']].groupby("col1")['COUNT'].sum()
count_col1 = count_col1.reset_index(drop=False)
count_col1.rename({'COUNT':'COUNT_COL1'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
ix = count_col1[count_col1.COUNT_COL1>1].index
count_col1.drop(ix, inplace=True)

df = df.merge(count_col1, on='col1', how='left')
ix = df[df.COUNT_COL1.notnull()].index
df.loc[ix, 'COUNT'] = 0
df.drop("COUNT_COL1", inplace=True, axis=1)
```

Comment: thinking about this now

Comment: It looks like this fails on case D where there is only 1 row with col1 = D, but the idea of Counting values is interesting. I'll think about if I can use this in a different way on my actual problem.

Comment: Sorry, missed your case D indeed. Just edited the answer, it keeps using the same method (there may be typos though, I didn't tried it with your sample dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

Lets try

```
df['newCol']=np.where((df.Col1.eq(df.Col1.shift(-1))|df.Col1.shift(1).eq(df.Col1))&df.Col2.ne(df.Col2.shift(-1)),1,0)



 Col1  Col2  newCol
0    a     1       1
1    a     2       1
2    b     1       0
3    b     1       0
4    c     1       1
5    c     2       1
6    c     3       1
7    d     1       0
```

Comment: Looking at the new answers now, thanks everyone!

Comment: Ah, first concern here @wwnde, is that the order of the rows is not actually guaranteed. Does the .shift operator rely on that? Sorry I hadn't included that in my question

Comment: Can sort rows on Col1 and Col2 to achieve desired order. Shuffle them up and will get you solution

Comment: Duh on "just sort the array" thanks for that, I had a brain fart.